# Gilmans and carbon dioxide

Tags: reactivity, organometallic-compounds

I know that Grignards react with carbon dioxide to give carboxylate anions.

But will Gilmans do the same? Will Gilmans react with carbon dioxide in a productive fashion?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? Will Gilman reagents react with carbon dioxide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, cuprates do react with carbon dioxide to give access to carboxylates / carboxylic acids.

Running a SciFinder search, I do not see any examples of traditional Gilman reagents (alkyl cuprates) reacting directly with carbon dioxide. This shouldn't be surprising though, since the alkyl cuprates are generated from the corresponding alkyl lithium compound. If you have the alkyl lithium compound, then you can just react that with carbon dioxide directly.

A more synthetically useful situation is when the alkyl cuprate is reacted with an alkyne, resulting in a syn-addition of the alkyl group and copper across the alkyne. The alkenyl (vinyl) cuprate can then be trapped with carbon dioxide to give a carboxylate.

[image]

A couple examples from the literature:

[Z,​Z-​Dienes via acetylene carbocupration:  synthesis of navel orangeworm pheromone](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(00)98174-7)

[The silylcupration of acetylenes: a synthesis of vinylsilanes](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/P19810002527)

Also check the write up in *Organic Reactions* by Lipshutz (the world's expert in organocopper chemistry).

More complicated (non-Gilman) organocopper compounds have been reacted with carbon dioxide to give copper carboxylates:

[Carbon-​carbon coupling of activated alkanes with carbon dioxide by [(phen)​(Ph3P)​Cu(O2COH)​]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-328X(88)80403-0)

[Synthesis, Structure, and CO2 Reactivity of a Two-​Coordinate (Carbene)​copper(I) Methyl Complex](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/om034368r)

Comment: Informative, as usual.  But I still wonder about Gilman reagents adding to carbon dioxide.  Gilman reagents behave like a weaker base than Grignards or alkyl lithium reagents.  Gilman reagents don't typically have the "oomph" to add to ketones, while the stronger Grignards and alkyl lithiums do.  Further evidence that Gilman reagents are weaker, they typically add in conjugate fashion to alpha-beta unsaturated enones, while the other reagents can add directly to the carbonyl.  Like I said, just wondering.

Comment: @ron I bet that reaction works... The trend in cuprate reactivity is that spC-Cu is essentially unreactive, sp2C-Cu is more reactive, and sp3C-Cu is the most reactive. In the examples I listed, the vinyl cuprates react with CO2. Also, although I've never seen it directly compared to other carbonyls, I think CO2 is a pretty reactive electrophile with the two oxygens pulling electrons away from carbon through resonance. Toss in the fact that it's really small with two equivalent LUMO's so there are many possible modes that a nucleophile can approach.